# How to create a custom frame for Youtube embedded player?

Tags: html, css, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

i'm developing a website in which i want to show videos from youtube (using the embedded player offered from YT) modifying the frame outside the player.

More specific, i want to create a television img in which, instead of the tv screen, i want to show my videos.

I've tried to create a photo from photoshop cancelling the screen, but then, in HTML, if i choose that img as background-div photo or inserting it as < img src="" />, using z-indexes, i cannot click on the "play" button of my video, because it is covered by the "television" div.
Any Help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could slice up your image into a top/left/right/bottom section, and place them around the youtube video (overlaying the edges of the youtube player)

**[I've mocked up a jsfiddle that uses background-color instead of the sliced up images.](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/ZkUYa/)**

HTML:

```
<div id="TV">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="bottom"></div>
    <div id="playButton">play<div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#TV{position:absolute;width:500px;height:300px;}
#top{position:absolute;top:0;width:500px;height:20px;background-color:red;}
#left{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:20px;height:300px;background-color:red;}
#right{position:absolute;top:0;right:0;width:20px;height:300px;background-color:red;}
#bottom{position:absolute;bottom:0;width:500px;height:20px;background-color:red;}
#playButton{height:100px;width:100px;border-radius:100px;background-color:yellow;left: 200px;position: absolute;top: 90px;}
#playButton:hover{background-color:red;}
```

I also have an example of this in action, where you would draw on the canvas in the middle of the "frame" images.  [Here](http://mathiasprovinggrounds.com/WinterWunderman/)

The only caveat is that you need to use fixed heights and widths, and absolute positions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a code html with it you can insert a YT video

```html
 <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5L3wKniOnro?autoplay=1" width="600" height="400" allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```